# sql update if row exists, insert if not - in one line

Tags: mysql

I read several answers in here and though it might look like a duplicate I think the scenario is a bit specific.

I have a table with the following fields

> id | language_id | item_code | item_name

**what I want** is when I try to input a new line, to check with `language_id` and `item_code` if it exists, and update or insert based on the result. I know I could do something like

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE language_id=1 AND item_code=PH001

and check the number of rows returned,

what I would like is *if* I can do it on one line and how

Comment: @JimGarrison I did read the manual, but you didnt read my question :D, `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, where am looking for duplicate row `WHERE language_id and item_code` equal the data. If you are going to make fun of me at least be productive thank you.

Comment: If you're going to be checking for duplicates those columns should be indexed.  If the composite key is not unique then you have amgibuity where in some cases you update but in others you insert (otherwise you'd never have duplicate values in the composite key). Therefore you should create a unique index and use upsert syntax.

Comment: @JimGarrison You see with your second comment I feel like I learned more than I would on my own in a week, in just a few lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to be checking for duplicates those columns should be indexed. If the composite key is not unique then you have amgibuity where in some cases you update but in others you insert (otherwise you'd never have duplicate values in the composite key).

Therefore you should create a unique index and use [upsert syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
    If exists (SELECT * FROM table WHERE language_id=1 AND item_code=PH001)
    Then
    update statement
    ELSE 
    Insert statement
```

Comment: Downvoter, can you let me know what is problem with my query?

Comment: I would like to know that as well :P

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but the query will give an error

Comment: @Gervs, can you explain why? Because i am not sure.

Comment: When you run a query it should always start with SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, CREATE, DROP, SET, ALTER etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as SQL Query:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE language_id=1 AND item_code='PH001') > 0 THEN UPDATE_QUERY;
ELSE INSERT_QUERY;
END IF;
```